# Using awk remove columns that are "-" on the first line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the table

```
M       -       A       A       -
-       A       G       -       -
M       -       -       -       G
```

and I want to perform: **if any column of the first line contains "-", skip printing the column**

The expected output is

```
M       A       A 
-       G       - 
M       -       -
```

I have tried something like this but didn't work

```
awk 'NR==1 && $i!="-" {print $i}'
```

Does anyone know how to correct the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation of [Ed Morton's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557733/116858), which remembers which fields are not `-` in the first line by their field number, and then re-forms each record in the input according to the saved indexes in the array `out` before printing the new record:

```awk
FNR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        if ($i != "-") out[++nf] = i
}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
        a[i] = $(out[i])

    $0 = ""

    for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
        $i = a[i]

    print
}
```

Here, I've sacrificed a bit of efficiency for readability, by reconstructing the record in a separate loop, rather than printing the required fields in a single loop in the second block.

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
M A A
- G -
M - -
```

Running with tabs as output field separator:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' -f script.awk file
M       A       A
-       G       -
M       -       -
```

---

A slightly too long one-liner that depends on the input data being tab-delimited:

```
$ cut -f "$(awk -v OFS=',' '{ nf=split($0,a); $0=""; for (i=1; i<=nf; ++i) if (a[i]!="-") $(++NF)=i; print; exit }' file)" file
M       A       A
-       G       -
M       -       -
```

This uses `awk` to output the *field numbers* that are not `-` on the first line as a comma-separated list.  This list is then handed over to `cut -f` which does the actual output of the data from the file.  Note that the filename (here simply `file`) is given twice on the command line, once for `awk` and then again for `cut`.

Comment: In the first script you could do `split($0,a); $0=""; for (i=1;i<=nf;i++) $i=a[out[i]]` and so remove the need for the second loop but actually `rec=$(out[1]); for (i=2; i<=nf; i++) {
        rec = rec OFS $(out[i])
    }; $0=rec` would be more efficient as it doesn't require awk to recompile nor resplit the record every iteration through the loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i != "-") {
            f[++numOutFlds] = i
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=numOutFlds; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
M A A
- G -
M - -
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` implicitly loops over input records (lines) and files, but not fields which you must do explicitly. In your case you need to loop over fields in the first (header) line to decide which columns to include, and then loop over fields in *every* line (header and nonheader) to include the desired columns on that line.

You aren't clear if you want to look for header fields that are *equal to* (the string) "-" or that may have it as a *(sub)string*. I also assume you have (all) single tabs as field separators, not multiple spaces which would be more tedious (and cannot be distinguished visually from your post).

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)s[i]=$i!="-"} {x="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(s[i])x=x FS $i;print substr(x,2)}'
# for _matches_ "-" instead of _equals_ "-" change $i!="-" to $i!~/-/
# note if a nonheader line has more fields than the header did,
# all extra fields are nonselected (as if their header field was/matched -)

# or (re)use the flags for both what to include _and_ when to terminate the line
awk -F"\t" 'NR==1{t=RS;for(i=NF;i;i--)if(s[i]=($i!="-"?t:""))t=FS} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(s[i])printf "%s%s",$i,s[i]}'
# some people may consider this too clever
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl.

For the first line, build an array `@A` of  indices for which the field is non dash.

Then for all lines, including the first, print only those fields from `@F` whose indices are in `@A`.

```
$ perl -lane '$, = "\t";
    $. == 1 and @A = grep $F[$_] ne "-", 0..$#F;
    print @F[@A];
' file
```

**Output:**

```
M   A   A
-   G   -
M   -   -
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using `sed`, although the code is with GNU sed in extended regex mode, but that is just as a cure for `backslashitis`.

The method is to create a map from first line. The fields to be kept are mapoed as x others as a dash. Save this map in the hold.

Then for all lines, append this map and place a marker at the BOL.

In a loop we keep deleting the leading field of the current line if we see a \n- AND advance the marker to the next field.

The looping ends when this marker collides with the newline between current line and hold space, (due to the G command).

```
$ sed -Ee '
    1{
      h
      y/-/\n/
      s/\S+/x/g;s/[[:blank:]]+//g
      y/\n/-/
      x
    }

    G;s/^/\n/

    :a
      s/\n(\S+\s*)(.*\n)x/\1\n\2/
      s/\n(\S+\s*)(.*\n)-/\n\2/
    /\n\n/!ba

    s/\s+$//
' file
```

**Results**

```
M       A       A
-       G       -
M       -       -
```